# PopOver Open in Leftside up+iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I want to open a popover on button click event.
Like below image:
[image]

But what i m getting is:

[image]

The Code i had used for the popover is:

```
PopOver *PopOver_obj=[[PopOver alloc]initWithNibName:@"PopOver_ipad" bundle:nil ];      
UIPopoverController  *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:PopOver_obj];     
popoverController.delegate = self;     
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f,200.0f);
popoverController.popoverContentSize = maximumLabelSize;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100,100, 200.0f, 100.0f);  
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: I think not possible your requirement using popover ,alternate solution is take view Click on button

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

For iOS 5 you can use `popoverLayoutMargins` property of the popover to set an inset relative to the device's screen edges. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for more detail.

---

As far as I can see from your screenshot you have a black colored view and a white one but you are showing the popup in their superview.

You can try using `- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated` method and pass the white view as the `view` argument of the method and `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp` for the `arrowDirections argument`.

I think that might restrict the popover to go outside the view thus keeping it under your `+` button.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reple i had used this line:-    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES] ; But then also it is giving mew same output as shown in above image

Comment: Tell me this - in your second screen shoot is the white background a different view than self.view OR is it self.view?